# Ошибка aiogram 3

Tags: python, aiogram-3.x

При нажатии на Inline кнопки в личных сообщениях все работает отлично, но если сделать это в группе то вылезет ошибка : Cause exception while process update id=11439152 by bot id=6476844061
TelegramBadRequest: Telegram server says - Bad Request: message to edit not found

```py
from aiogram import types, Dispatcher, Bot
from aiogram.filters import Command
from aiogram.types import Message
from aiogram.utils.keyboard import InlineKeyboardBuilder

bot = Bot("6476844061:AAEt9Drg2fRihI_WhAYCZTh_Xz5wvF6J8Ns")
text1 = "‍| з'їсти\n| вбити\n| вдарити\n| обійняти\n| налякати\n| заспівати\n✋| дати п'ять\n| cлідкувати\n❤️| поцілувати\n| привітатися\n| обматерити\n| прогулятись\n| поспівчувати\n☢| кинути ядерку\n| вдягнути маску клоуна\n| записати в Зошит Смерті"
text2 = '<b>call</b> - скликати\n<b>ban</b> - забанити\n<b>mute</b> - замутити\n<b>unmute</b> - розмутити\n<b>offchat</b> - вимкнути чат\n<b>onchat</b> - ввімкнути чат\n\n(Тільки для типу группи: <b>Public</b>)'
text3 = "⚠ Команда повинна бути відповіддю на повідомлення."
dp = Dispatcher()
allow_stickers = False


@dp.message(Command("start"))
async def start(message: Message):
    builder = InlineKeyboardBuilder()
    builder.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Додати мене в группу", url="https://t.me/babashuras_bot?startgroup"))
    await message.answer(
        f'Привіт, <b>{message.from_user.first_name}</b> ! Я баба Шура.\nЩоб відкрити меню бота: /help\n\nІнформація про бота: <a href="https://t.me/babaShurasChannel">Баба Шура </a> \nПо всім питанням сюди: @Vip_frog\nБудемо дуже вдячні за поширення.',
        disable_web_page_preview=True,
        parse_mode='html',
        reply_markup=builder.as_markup()
    )


@dp.message(Command("help"))
async def start(message: Message):
    builder = InlineKeyboardBuilder()
    builder.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="RP| Команди", callback_data="com1"))
    builder.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Mod| Команди", callback_data="com2"))
    await message.answer(
        'Привіт! Це меню Баби Шури!\n\nОберіть потрібну вам кнопку:',
        reply_markup=builder.as_markup()
    )


@dp.callback_query()
async def callbacks(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    builder = InlineKeyboardBuilder()
    builder.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=" Назад ", callback_data="return"))
    builder1 = InlineKeyboardBuilder()
    builder1.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="RP| Команди", callback_data="com1"))
    builder1.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Mod| Команди", callback_data="com2"))
    if callback.data == "com1": await bot.edit_message_text(
        chat_id=callback.from_user.id,
        message_id=callback.message.message_id, text=text1,
        reply_markup=builder.as_markup()
    )
    if callback.data == "com2": await bot.edit_message_text(
        chat_id=callback.from_user.id,
        message_id=callback.message.message_id,
        text=text2,
        parse_mode="html",
        reply_markup=builder.as_markup()
    )
    if callback.data == "return": await bot.edit_message_text(
        chat_id=callback.from_user.id,
        message_id=callback.message.message_id,
        text="Привіт! Це меню Баби Шури!\n\nОберіть потрібну вам кнопку:",
        parse_mode="html",
        reply_markup=builder1.as_markup()
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

Потому что вы пытаетесь изменить сообщение в личном чате, когда указываете
`chat_id=callback.from_user.id`

Укажите
`chat_id=callback.message.chat.id`

и все будет работать

```
    if callback.data == "com1": await bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=callback.message.chat.id, message_id=callback.message.message_id, text=text1,reply_markup=builder.as_markup())
    if callback.data == "com2": await bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=callback.message.chat.id, message_id=callback.message.message_id, text=text2,parse_mode="html",reply_markup=builder.as_markup())
    if callback.data == "return": await bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=callback.message.chat.id, message_id=callback.message.message_id, text="Привіт! Це меню Баби Шури!\n\nОберіть потрібну вам кнопку:",parse_mode="html",reply_markup=builder1.as_markup())
```

P.S. Лучше не обрабатывать все коллбеки в одной функции, а сделать отдельную функцию для каждого коллбека

```
@dp.callback_query(lambda call: call.data == "com1")
async def callbacks(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    ...


@dp.callback_query(lambda call: call.data == "com2")
async def callbacks(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    ...
```